# for...of iteration and destructuring with an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

According to the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#For_of_iteration_and_destructuring), here is how to use destructuring inside a `for of` loop:

```
var people = [
  {
    name: 'Mike Smith',
    family: {
      mother: 'Jane Smith',
      father: 'Harry Smith',
      sister: 'Samantha Smith'
    },
    age: 35
  },
  {
    name: 'Tom Jones',
    family: {
      mother: 'Norah Jones',
      father: 'Richard Jones',
      brother: 'Howard Jones'
    },
    age: 25
  }
];

for (var {name: n, family: {father: f}} of people) {
  console.log('Name: ' + n + ', Father: ' + f);
}

// "Name: Mike Smith, Father: Harry Smith"
// "Name: Tom Jones, Father: Richard Jones"
```

My question is, what would the correct destructuring syntax be in case the `family` object was located inside an array, like this:

```
var people = [
  {
    name: 'Tom Jones',
    family: [
     {
      mother: 'Norah Jones',
      father: 'Richard Jones',
      brother: 'Howard Jones'
     }
    ],
    age: 25
  }
];
```

(Note the extra set of [square brackets])

Attempting to destructure using:

```
for (var {name: n, family[0]: {father: f}} of people) {
  console.log('Name: ' + n + ', Father: ' + f);
}
```

gives an `Unexpected token` error at the square bracket.

So in this example, how do I use destructuring to assign a value to `f`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want the array structure represented, not the array index access.

```js
var people = [{
  name: 'Tom Jones',
  family: [{
    mother: 'Norah Jones',
    father: 'Richard Jones',
    brother: 'Howard Jones'
  }],
  age: 25
}];

// Describe the structure -v-----------v
for (var {name: n, family: [{father: f}]} of people) {
  console.log('Name: ' + n + ', Father: ' + f);
}
```

Of course, this assumes you want only the first member. If you want more, you can use the rest syntax.

```js
var people = [{
  name: 'Tom Jones',
  family: [{
    mother: 'Norah Jones',
    father: 'Richard Jones',
    brother: 'Howard Jones'
  }],
  age: 25
}];

for (var {name: n, family: [{father: f}, ...rem]} of people) {
  console.log('Name: ' + n + ', Father: ' + f);
  console.log("Remaining values: %s", rem.length);
}
```

Comment: this works great! thanks. Don't need the rest syntax right now but filing it away for future reference

Answer (score 2):

You can use array destructuring (any remaining array elements are simply ignored):

```
                        // vv            vv
for (var {name: n, family: [ {father: f} ] } of people)
  // ...
```

Alternatively, since arrays are just objects, you can use object destructuring with the index as key:

```
                        // vvvvv            vv
for (var {name: n, family: { 0: {father: f} } } of people)
  // ...
```

Comment: yep, this works too. I would mark as answer but other guy was first, and has less points than you :) thanks friend